# Nex.js Module path aliases not clickable in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js

I'm trying to get module path aliases clickable in vscode

```
// Ctrl+click Working fine
import Layout from "src/components/layout/Layout";

// Not working
import SEO from "@components/SEO";
```

My JSconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["/src/components/*"],
      "@sections/*": ["/src/sections/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["/src/assets/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried everything without success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
      "@sections/*": ["./src/sections/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["./src/assets/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Had same issue with 'Go to definition'. And on the end I found it was not working for me because I had both tsconfig.json and jsconfig.json in the project.

Seems when tsconfig.json is present, alias setting from jsconfig.json are ignored.

As I want gradually convert stuff into Typescript, but have lot of .js files I kept `tsconfig.json`, and added `"**/*.js"` to the `"include"` list, so it sees also .js files. Now aliases in vscode are clickable.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": [
        "components/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/*.js"
  ]
}
```